# How to display notification on success_action, when using Angular store? (v6)

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx

I want to delete an item in my app (Angular version 6). Previously I was calling service directly, but now using ngrx/store and ngrx/effects, and dispatching actions.

As shown in the code, I could easily show a notification, if the delete was successful.

### Question

**How will my component know, if the delete operation was successful or not?**

**How can I show a notification now, when using actions?**

Thanks in advance.

---

### Code

**component.ts**

```js
constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
) { }

deleteTopic(topicId: number) {

    // new way: dispatch action to delete the topic
    this.store.dispatch(new fromCourse.DeleteTopic(topicId));


    // old way
    // this.courseService.deleteTopic(topicId)
    //                   .subscribe(
    //                     data => {
    //                       this.ngOnInit();
    //                       this.snackBar.open('successfully deleted');
    //                     },
    //                     err => {
    //                       if (err.status === 403) {
    //                           this.snackBar.open('you dont have access to delete');
    //                       }
    //                     }
    //                   );

}
```

**effects**

```js
@Effect()
deleteTopic$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromCourse.DeleteTopic>(CourseActionTypes.DELETE_TOPIC),
    switchMap((action) => {
        return this.courseService.deleteTopic(action.payload).pipe( // payload is the topicId to be deleted
        map(data => new fromCourse.DeleteTopicSuccess(action.payload) ) // send the topicId to reducer, to update state
        );
    })
);
```

**reducer**

```js
case CourseActionTypes.DELETE_TOPIC_SUCCESS: {
    // find the index of topic and splice it

    return {
        // return new state
    };
}
```

Comment: createSelector for delete topic success and use selector to subscribe the data

Comment: your suggestion requires a full explanation, please provide an actual answer - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible choices here, first might not work, depending on your setup:

(1) Using an @Effect, trigger the notification in the `CourseActionTypes.DELETE_TOPIC_SUCCESS` action. This will work unless you need access to data in the component itself when triggering the notification.

(2) Listen for the `CourseActionTypes.DELETE_TOPIC_SUCCESS` action being fired in the component like this:

```
import { ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store'

constructor(private actionsSubject$: ActionsSubject) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.actionsSubject$.pipe(
    filter((action: any) => action.type === CourseActionTypes.DELETE_TOPIC_SUCCESS)
  ).subscribe(action => {
    console.log(action.type)
    console.log(action.payload)
    // fire notification here
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your time and gving the solution. This worked (solution 2) flawlessly :thumbsup: